# Oxtoby Thm 5.4 Bernstein sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory, baire-category

I am reading Measure and Category of Oxtoby. I have a question about Theorem 5.4 added below. I think I understand the construction of Bernstein sets, and also the main line of the Proof. My question is mush more basic I think:

> Suppose that every measurable subset of either $B$ or $B'$ is a Nullset, and any subset of $B$ or $B'$ that has the property of Baire is of first category. Why, Does it implies that $B$ is non-measurable?

Am I missing something obvious? 
Thank you for your help!!
Shir

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I read this great book long time ago! Suppose that $B$ is measurable then its measure must be zero (since every measurable subset of $B$ is a nullset) and similarly the measure of $B'$ must also be zero which implies that $\Bbb{R}$ is a nullset. I am right ?

Comment: Yes.. as far as I cam judge, you are very right.. Thank you!!